# Extract all text smileys from a string in android

Tags: android, emoticons

I have a string like hello :) world :D. I want to extract these characters :) :D :P from above string and want to replace these with emoticons.

I want a regexp pattern to find all these type of smiley characters from a string so that I can replace them with the corresponding images of smileys.

How can I do this, do anyone have that regexp by which we can extract all these type of characters.

This would be a great help, thank you so much.

Thank a lot in advanced.